# Testing Java code with Groovy under Intellij: unable to resolve class GroovyTestCase

Tags: java, groovy, intellij-idea, junit

I need to write a short test for some Java code. I used CTRL+SHIFT+T to generate one with IntelliJ, and selected "Groovy JUnit" as the testing library, then wrote the following test:

```
package util
class FibonacciHeapTest extends GroovyTestCase {
    FibonacciHeap<Integer> heap

    void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        heap = new FibonacciHeap<>()
    }

    void testAddInOrder() {
        testForItems 1..1000
    }


    private void testForItems(Range<Integer> items) {
        items.each {heap << it}
        assertEquals heap.size, items.to
        items.each {assertEquals heap.remove(), it}
    }
}
```

However, when I right click on the test case in the project window, I don't get the "Run All Tests" option that I normally do with JUnit tests, and the compiler throws the following error:

```
Information:2/4/15 8:15 PM - Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 2 sec
/home/patrick/IdeaProjects/hackerrank/src/test/java/util/FibonacciHeapTest.groovy
Error:(3, 1) Groovyc: unable to resolve class util.FibonacciHeap
Error:(9, 1) Groovyc: unable to resolve class GroovyTestCase
```

Trying to import `GroovyTestCase` or `FibonacciHeap` manually causes the same error. IntelliJ does not add any import statements when I let autocomplete finish the names for me, like it usually would with Java code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: shouldn't this be `groovy/util/...`?

Comment: @cfrick The project is in Java. `src/test/java` is marked as the test directory, and the class that I'm testing is `util.FibonacciHeap`.

Comment: well it might depend on your setup.  but a) the regular place to put your groovy files would be src/(main|test)/groovy/package/class.(java|groovy) and b) more often than not, if groovy (or intellij) can not find your stuff, there is something wrong with package/directory and/or file/class name

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This worked for me :

- Open Gradle window (on right side in my case)
- Click on refresh button
- Done

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How do I get Gradle to open up in the normal IntelliJ version?

Comment: @Christian I don't know, I'm only using Androdi Studio

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem with creating test classes in IntelliJ, and it was solved when creating a new directory outside of the com.company folder (where I had the class I wanted to test).

1. Create a new directory for the test classes on the same level as your src folder
2. Right click on your new test directory, and "Mark directory as" --> "Test Resources Root"
3. Now create a test class, which should automatically be added to your test directory.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Build -> Rebuild project in the IDE itself (as opposed to maven, in my case) did it for me.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my case, what I did to resolve the issue was rather simple.

- Close IntelliJ
- Open the attached homepage...
- Remove your project by clicking on the `x` then...
- Click on `Import Project`, Navigate to the `build.graddle` file of your project and open.

[image]

That was it and all the Red highlightings disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need add groovy-all rather then groovy,such as :

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure Groovy SDK first. See the screenshot

[image]

More detailed description in the official document: [Configuring Global, Project and Module SDKs](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html)

Comment: How do I get there? What happens when I get there? This answer should be more thorough

Comment: I also get this error (groovyc: unable to resolve class groovy.util.GroovyTestCase) and adding groovy-all:2.4.3 to the dependencies (as suggested above) did not help.

Comment: I solved it by adding the junit jar to dependencies in addition to the groovy jar

Comment: Groovy is a library not a SDK in IntelliJ. The JDK should be setup as the SDK and groovy as a library dependency (as shown in the screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

As @sman591 pointed out in a comment, if you are getting the error:

```
groovyc: unable to resolve class groovy.util.GroovyTestCase
```

and you already have groovy as a dependency then you are probably just missing the junit dependency.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA I re-imported the project. It worked then.
I closed idea. I removed `.idea` folder in the project. And I imported the project.

Then I needed to set up Groovy, see previous answers, mark test directory as test source in all modules of my project.

Answer (score 0):

I was selecting the root folder which had `build.gradle` file in it, but it didn't work.

**Steps followed** are similar to @Pila

1. close the project from intellij
2. remove `.idea, log, out` folders
3. go to intellij dashboard
4. import project from existing resources
5. select `build.gradle` file <-- *this is important*
6. now you should see all the tasks are getting build in the background, and once build is finished all red lines are gone.